Why do we need notch filters in Raman? (building upon previous)
Similar but different question to Why is a notch filter required for Raman Spectroscopy?
The answer there was that the incident light needs to be filtered out, as it's several orders of magnitude more intense than Raman.
However, in the case of back scattered or 90 degree orientation of the Raman radiation to the incident light, the only 'noise' present is Rayleigh or fluoroscence. The first of these can be eliminated as it will equal the wavelength of the incident light. And if the OOM of the Raman shift is known, fluoroscence can also be eliminated from the data as it will be sitting at a much higher frequency.
So why do we need filters for Rayleigh and fluoroscence? Why not eliminate the noise digitally?

You might not need filters, but that depends on how good your spectrometer and detector is. And it is almost always better to eliminate potential noise before it becomes actual noise in your data.

All detectors have a finite a dynamic range, the ability to operate simultaneously in the presence of both the smallest and the largest signals within the specified accuracy. Once this dynamic range is exceeded the smallest signal will usually be suppressed and distorted by the larger signals. The distortion in the presence of detection noise also becomes "randomized" and not really amenable to post-detection removal. This is why it is always a good idea to remove as much noise as possible and also minimize the signal's dynamic range before any detection.
